getting infinite loop in shiny when trying to get value into UI through several levels of submodules
I am getting an infinite loop in the below code in shiny R application (the code is a minimal example that reproduces the issue in my bigger actual app).
The code appends a namespace of the button clicked to the verbatimTextOutput.
The key here is to transfer the value (in this case triggered by button click) from submodule to module to the level of ui. I tried returning reactives from inside modules, but could not avoid the infinite loop. Please suggest what should be fixed to function properly.
Thanks.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text_input", "Input text"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_output"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  updated_text <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$text_input, {
    req(input$text_input)
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Title",
      size = "l",
      module_ui("module"),
      footer = modalButton("Close")
    ))
    # Update the text with the module result
    updated_text(module_server("module", input$text_input))
  })

  output$text_output <- renderText(updated_text())
}

module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidPage(
    uiOutput(ns("module"))
  )
}

module_server <- function(id, input_text) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      module_rv <- reactiveValues(text = "")

      output$module <- renderUI({
        do.call(navlistPanel,
                c(id = ns("navlist"),
                  lapply(X = 1:3,
                         FUN = function(x) {
                           submodule_return_value <- submodule_server(x)
                           # Update module text with submodule result when button is clicked
                           module_rv$text <- submodule_return_value
                           #create submodule UI
                           submodule_ui(ns(x))
                         })
                )
        )
      })

      # Append the value returned by submodule stored in the reactive value
      return(paste(input_text, "__", module_rv$text))
    }
  )
}

submodule_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tabPanel(title = paste("Title", id),
           uiOutput(ns("submoduleUI"))
  )
}

submodule_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      # Reactive value to store the value to be returned by submodule
      submodule_rv <- reactiveVal()

      output$submoduleUI <- renderUI({
        do.call(tabsetPanel,
                c(id = ns("tabset"),
                  lapply(X = 1:3,
                         FUN = function(x) {
                           if (x == 1) {
                             tabPanel(paste("Tab", ns(x)),
                                      actionButton(ns("bttn"), paste("Button", ns(x))))
                           } else {
                             tabPanel(paste("Tab", ns(x)),
                                      verbatimTextOutput(ns(paste0(x,"-verb"))))
                           }
                         })
                )
        )
      })

      # When button is clicked, return namespace with the input
      observeEvent(input$bttn, {
        submodule_rv(ns(input$bttn))
      })

      return(submodule_rv())
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


After I've put some traces in both modules, it seems the submodule_server is called again and again. It probably creates this "bttn" actionButton multiple times and triggers it's observeEvent because input$bttn is already valuated with 1 after you click the button a first time.

Step.1 - Debug
Add traces to the different server functions like: cat("Launch server \n")
Console output after clicking the button:
Launch server
Launch module_server 
Launch submodule_server
Launch submodule_server
Launch submodule_server
Launch submodule_server
Launch submodule_server
Launch submodule_server
...

From there it seems the submodule_server is launched multiple times (and the submodule observeEvent is triggered each time a new instance is launched).
Step.2 - Solution
I think one approach is to create a reactiveVal object at the main server level
and pass it's reference to the module / submodule.
I suggest reading the 'bible' to understand about it: Advanced R
By doing this, the content (value) of the reactiveVal object will be updated
at the submodule server level only, and used at the main server level.
The whole idea behind this is to split the calling (launching) of the module / submodule server functions from the use of it's "output" (the values computed inside them).
Also the main input$text_input value will not be sent to the module, as we can
now concatenate it with the content of the reactiveVal object in the main server.
library(shiny)

# -- main ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text_input", "Input text"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_output"))


# -- main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # -- reactive to pass to module / submodule
  updated_text <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  # -- launch module server
  # send the reference of the reactiveVal as argument (not it's value)
  module_server("module", updated_text)
  
  # -- observe main btn & display modal
  observeEvent(input$text_input, {
    req(input$text_input)
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Title",
      size = "l",
      module_ui("module"),
      footer = modalButton("Close")))})
  
  # -- main text output
  # it will be updated each time the content of the reactiveVal is updated
  # by the submodule
  output$text_output <- renderText(
    paste(input$text_input, "__", updated_text()))
  
}


# -- module ----

module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput(ns("module"))
  )
}


module_server <- function(id, updated_text) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # launch submodule instances & update module ui
      output$module <- renderUI({
        do.call(navlistPanel,
                c(id = ns("navlist"),
                  lapply(X = 1:3,
                         FUN = function(x) {
                           
                           # launch submodule server & pass again the 
                           # reference of the reactiveVal
                           submodule_server(x, updated_text)
                           
                           #create submodule UI
                           submodule_ui(ns(x))})))})
      
    }
  )
}


# -- sub module ----

submodule_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(title = paste("Title", id),
           uiOutput(ns("submoduleUI"))
  )
}


submodule_server <- function(id, updated_text) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns

      # build submodule ui
      output$submoduleUI <- renderUI({
        do.call(tabsetPanel,
                c(id = ns("tabset"),
                  lapply(X = 1:3,
                         FUN = function(x) {
                           if (x == 1) {
                             tabPanel(paste("Tab", ns(x)),
                                      actionButton(ns("bttn"), paste("Button", ns(x))))
                           } else {
                             tabPanel(paste("Tab", ns(x)),
                                      verbatimTextOutput(ns(paste0(x,"-verb"))))}})))})
      
      
      # When button is clicked, update the reactiveVal
      # this will trigger the observeEvent in the main server :)
      observeEvent(input$bttn, {
        updated_text(ns(input$bttn))})
      
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Additional comment
The same approach (use the reference of the reactive object) will also
work for the module server return value. A module can return the reference of
a reactive that will be used at the calling level.
I just feel the above solution makes the code much easier to read as compared to cascading the return value of the submodule.

this is great - thank you! And the suggested workflow of passing the reactive through the chain of modules is quite universal - will use
